# How to delete selected object from localstorage

Tags: javascript, html, local-storage

I am looking for a way to delete one object in an array, without having to delete all the local storage, like by using `local.storage.clear`

I tried using `Local.storage.removeItem` but it didn't work. I also used `JSON.stringify` to set the item, is there any alternative? Thank you!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
    <p id="demo"></p>
    <input id="click"type="checkbox" onclick="savelocalstorage()">
    </button>

    <script>
        var n=0;

        function savelocalstorage()
        {
            var myarray = [
                { format: "jpg", name: "Alice" },
                { format: "jpg", name: "Jack" },
            ];

            if (n % 2 == 1) {
                document.getElementById("click").checked = false;
                localStorage.removeItem(myarray[0]);
            } else {
                document.getElementById("click").checked = true;
                localStorage["myarray"] = JSON.stringify(myarray[0]);
            }

            n++;
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: In the localStorage you are saving in "myarray", why are you trying to delete a different thing? Don't you have to do`localStorage.removeItem("myarray");`

Comment: @BrankVictoria should be right. You are passing in an object to look for to remove, but you should be looking for the item name ex: `localStorage.removeItem('itemName');`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're doing this:

`localStorage.removeItem(myarray[0]);`

But `myarray[0]` is an object, whereas the key you're storing the object in is the string `"myarray"`. Use the string in both cases.

Answer (score 2):

The key for localstorage must be a string, you are passing an object which cannot be a key

Comment: Actually he is passing "myarray" as key

Comment: Not here he isn't: `localStorage.removeItem(myarray[0]);`

Comment: Yes, but if you see what he is storing in the localStorage with key"myarray" is the whole array of objects using JSON.stringify, he is not storing the object itself

Comment: i see that @BrankVictoria

Comment: @vwvwvw Yes you can, but you need to store it using a key, I supossed you can use the stringify of the object as the key and value... Then you will remove it using the stringify again...

Answer (score 0):

You need to get the item from the local storage m the remove first element and store it back

```js
var n = 0;

function savelocalstorage() {
  var myarray = [{
      format: "jpg",
      name: "Alice"
    },
    {
      format: "jpg",
      name: "Jack"
    }
  ];

  if (n % 2 == 1) {
    document.getElementById("click").checked = false;
    // get the storage & remove the first element
    let itm = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('myarray')).shift();
    localStorage.setItem('myarray', JSON.stringify(itm));

  } else {
    document.getElementById("click").checked = true;
    localStorage.setItem("myarray",JSON.stringify(myarray[0]));
  }
  n++;
}
```

```html
<p id="demo"></p>
<input id="click" type="checkbox" onclick="savelocalstorage()">
```